# Elasticsearch max of field combined with a unique field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-7

I have an index with two fields:

- **name**: uuid
- **version**: long

I now only want to count the documents (on a very large index [1 million+ entries]) where the version of the name is the highest. For e.g. a query on an index with the following documents:

```
{name="a", version=1} 
{name="a", version=2}
{name="a", version=3}
{name="b", version=1}
```

... would return:

```
count=2
```

Is this somehow possible? I can not find a solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively describing a count of distinct names, which you can do with a [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html).

### Request:

```
GET test1/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "distinct_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "name.keyword"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "distinct_count" : {
      "value" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not deliver the count of the highest version for a name.

Comment: Yes it does. "value": 2 at the bottom of the object.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! It does not really matter what the highest version is. My question is not correct. I will mark this as the correct answer and open a new one. Thank you for your help!